# jQuery not finding next element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used the code which someone on another question provided me several days ago but I have changed the HTML of my page and now it doesn't work but I can't figure out why. It should be making the button have the **disabled** property once the counter hits **0** but it isn't. This is the HTML

So it should be making the element named `stop`

```
<td class="text-left my-timer" data-time="10">10</td>
<form method="POST">
    <td><button type="submit" name="stop" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-square btn-danger">Stop</button></td>
    <input type="text" name="aID" value="431" class="hidden">
</form>
```

This is the javascript code I was given. As you can see once the timer is at 0 it will then find the button and add the property of disabled to it.

```
$(function(){
  // loop over each element to activate
  $('td.my-timer').each(function(){
    // "this" inside "each" is current element
    var $elem = $(this), 
         // get the time value stored in data-time attribute
         sec = $elem.data('time');
    // instance specific interval
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
       sec--;
       var html = sec > 0 ? sec : "<b>Finished</b>";
       $elem.html(html);
       if( sec == 0){
          clearInterval(timer);
          $elem.next().find('submit').prop('disabled', true);
       }
    },1000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`submit` is not the HTML element. It is attribute.

Your selector is wrong.

Use **attribute-value selector**:

```
$elem.next().find('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
//                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can also use [`:submit`](https://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/) pseudo-selector as follow:

> Selects all elements of type submit.

```
$elem.next().find(':submit').prop('disabled', true);
//                ^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Your html is invalid as `form` can't be a child of `tr`, move the entire form to be a child of the second `td` element, then use the [:submit selector](http://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/) to find the submit button

```js
$(function() {
  // loop over each element to activate
  $('td.my-timer').each(function() {
    // "this" inside "each" is current element
    var $elem = $(this),
      // get the time value stored in data-time attribute
      sec = $elem.data('time');
    // instance specific interval
    var timer = setInterval(function() {
      sec--;
      var html = sec > 0 ? sec : "<b>Finished</b>";
      $elem.html(html);
      if (sec == 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        $elem.next().find(':submit').prop('disabled', true);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td class="text-left my-timer" data-time="10">10</td>
  <td>
    <form method="POST">
      <button type="submit" name="stop" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-square btn-danger">Stop</button>
      <input type="text" name="aID" value="431" class="hidden" />
    </form>
  </td>
</table>
```

```
<td class="text-left my-timer" data-time="10">10</td>
<td>
    <form method="POST">
        <button type="submit" name="stop" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-square btn-danger">Stop</button>
        <input type="text" name="aID" value="431" class="hidden"/>
    </form>
</td>
```